# CoreData-- how many NSFetchedResultsControllers do I need?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have  some data query in several ways. Is it enough to use just one NSFetchedResultsController for multiple types of queries, or do I need one per query type?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the data queried in various ways at the same time. I would suggest to use multiple NSFetchedResultsController. So you can react on changes of the data for each query.

Comment: `at the same time` is the key piece of information in this sentence.